# editing the jar files

Tags: java, hibernate, jar

I was using hibernate 3.5 with spring 3.2 in my application but now I have migrated hibernate to 4.2. I have some custom jar which are having hibernate 3.5 dependent code i.e **Session** class in org.hibernate.classic package so I need to update my class files kept in custom jar.

I used **JD GUI** tool to get java files, edited them accordingly and end up with a directory 
containing **META-INF** and **com** folder. Now if I try to make jar from this directory , again **META-INF** folder is being created(I know it happens). so now if I open this jar and delete the generated **META-INF** folder(I want my **META-INF** folder intact because it contain dependencies) then JAR becomes corrupt.

Kindly let me know the alternative. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite get it: so you replace the generated META-INF with the extracted one from the original jar? Did you check that the original META-INF content, e.g. manifest, service descriptors etc. don't reference anything that doesn't exist anymore? Could you elaborate on in what way the jar becomes corrupt? What errors/exceptions do you get? Oh and why are you decompiling the jar? Is the source code unavailable?

Comment: Yes Thomas..I don't have the source code. somehow I managed to make the JAR with all the changes I wanted and everything looks perfectly fine. I keep those jar in local maven repository but still they are not being recognized in eclipse. I think it is impossible to get the exact source code from class files no matter how good tool we use. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: that depends on the source and the tool used but there are many factors that will make a decompilation result be different from the original source (besides comments and whitespace changes), e.g. tool quality, inlined constants, debug information might be disabled etc.